# Does InfoPath still not support Managed Metadata?

Tags: metadata

I've heard that InfoPath 2010 does not support Managed MetaData. Is this still true ?
Does anyone have a workaround for this ? Like using webservices to use the Managed Metadata ?

Cheers,
Andre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that InfoPath 2010 does not support Managed MetaData controls, such as the Managed MetaData Picker.

A workaround is proposed here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/632190d9-663b-4ea6-82e8-5c1e7f2f57c5/

Scroll down and look at Jinchun Chen's answer. I haven't tested it myself but it sounds like a good workaround.

Another solution widely discussed is to create a custom web service using the Taxonomy API which can read Managed MetaData. The web service is just a wrapper around the Taxonomy web service which parses the XML string and returns it in a format which can be bound to InfoPath control.

Cheers, Björn

Comment: Hi Björn, as stated I was also thinking about using the webservices. Thanks for the link to Chen's answer. 
Cheers,
André